# Simultaneously recognising UIPanGestureRecognizer, UIRotationGestureRecognizer, and UIPinchGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uikit, uigesturerecognizer

I have the following code to simultaneously recognise pan, pinch, and rotate gesture recognizers. Problem is pan gesture does not work properly when the view is rotated. On horizontally dragging a rotated view, it also keeps moving up. Here is my code.

```
import UIKit

 class ViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

     private var transformEditingView:UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    
         self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    
        let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(transformViewGestureHandler(_:)))
        panGesture.delegate = self
        panGesture.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
    
        let pinchGesture = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(transformViewGestureHandler(_:)))
        pinchGesture.delegate = self
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(pinchGesture)
    
        let rotationGesture = UIRotationGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(transformViewGestureHandler(_:)))
        rotationGesture.delegate = self
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(rotationGesture)
    
        transformEditingView = UIView(frame: self.view.bounds.insetBy(dx: 100, dy: 100))
        transformEditingView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    
        self.view.addSubview(transformEditingView!)
    
        transformEditingView?.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0
        transformEditingView?.layer.borderWidth = 4.0
        transformEditingView?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
     }

// MARK: - Gestures for tansformEditingView

func transformUsingRecognizer(_ recognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, transform: CGAffineTransform) -> CGAffineTransform {
    
    if let rotateRecognizer = recognizer as? UIRotationGestureRecognizer {
        return transform.rotated(by: rotateRecognizer.rotation)
    }
    
    if let pinchRecognizer = recognizer as? UIPinchGestureRecognizer {
        let scale = pinchRecognizer.scale
        return transform.scaledBy(x: scale, y: scale)
    }
    
    if let panRecognizer = recognizer as? UIPanGestureRecognizer {
        let deltaX = panRecognizer.translation(in: self.view).x
        let deltaY = panRecognizer.translation(in: self.view).y
        
        return transform.translatedBy(x: deltaX, y: deltaY)
    }
    
    return transform
}

var initialTransform: CGAffineTransform?

var gestures = Set<UIGestureRecognizer>(minimumCapacity: 3)

@IBAction func transformViewGestureHandler(_ gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    
    switch gesture.state {
        
    case .began:
        if gestures.count == 0 {
            initialTransform = transformEditingView.transform
        }
        gestures.insert(gesture)
        
    case .changed:
        if var initialTransform = initialTransform  {
            gestures.forEach({ (gesture) in
                initialTransform = transformUsingRecognizer(gesture, transform: initialTransform)
            })
            transformEditingView.transform = initialTransform
            
        }
        
    case .ended:
        gestures.remove(gesture)
        
    default:
        break
    }
}

func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    
    return true
}
  }
```

EDIT: I found that the following change fixes the issue, but not sure why.

```
    let deltaX = panRecognizer.translation(in: transformEditingView).x
    let deltaY = panRecognizer.translation(in: transformEditingView).y
```

Comment: Quick search comes across this gist: https://gist.github.com/sketchytech/27e46e3f6abc083ee9749835e34cb125 ... seems to do a good job of pan / pinch / rotate.

Comment: @DonMag I doubt the gist you posted will work for simultaneous recognition of pinch and rotate gestures. For simultaneous recognition, you need to store triggered gestures in an array and process them sequentially as posted in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try -- seems to work well for simultaneous Pan / Rotate / Scale:

```
class PinchPanRotateViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    
    let testView: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.text = "TEST"
        v.textAlignment = .center
        v.textColor = .yellow
        
        v.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0
        v.layer.borderWidth = 4.0
        v.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        v.layer.masksToBounds = true

        //Enable multiple touch and user interaction
        v.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        v.isMultipleTouchEnabled = true
        
        return v
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .blue
        
        view.addSubview(testView)
        testView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 240, height: 180)
        testView.center = view.center
        
        //add pan gesture
        let gestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePan(_:)))
        gestureRecognizer.delegate = self
        testView.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
        
        //add pinch gesture
        let pinchGesture = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(handlePinch(_:)))
        pinchGesture.delegate = self
        testView.addGestureRecognizer(pinchGesture)
        
        //add rotate gesture.
        let rotate = UIRotationGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: #selector(handleRotate(_:)))
        rotate.delegate = self
        testView.addGestureRecognizer(rotate)
    }
    
    @objc func handlePan(_ pan: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        if pan.state == .began || pan.state == .changed {
            guard let v = pan.view else { return }
            let translation = pan.translation(in: self.view)
            v.center = CGPoint(x: v.center.x + translation.x, y: v.center.y + translation.y)
            pan.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)
        }
    }
    
    @objc func handlePinch(_ pinch: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
        guard let v = pinch.view else { return }
        v.transform = v.transform.scaledBy(x: pinch.scale, y: pinch.scale)
        pinch.scale = 1
    }
    
    @objc func handleRotate(_ rotate: UIRotationGestureRecognizer) {
        guard let v = rotate.view else { return }
        v.transform = v.transform.rotated(by: rotate.rotation)
        rotate.rotation = 0
    }
    
    func gestureRecognizer(_: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, this seems to work, except that I don't have a way to determine if all gesture recognizers have ended. It seems if one gesture recognizer has ended, so do others so I can safely update dataModel when anyone of them has ended and set a flag that data model is already updated.